# How to draw Cantor function in mathematica

Tags: mathematica-online

I want to have a close look on 1/2x+1/2*Cantor function,the website told me I can use CantorStaircase to draw it,but when I use it,Wolframalpha just always told me that they can't interpret.What should I do?

Comment: Show us the code you used.

Comment: So, are you asking about _Mathematica_ or WolframAlpha? If the latter, it's off topic here.

Answer (score 5):

It's working just fine,

```
f[x_] := 1/2 x + 1/2*CantorStaircase[x]

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]